# Create revision per feature branch

Tags: git, phabricator, arcanist

I am currently using Git and Arcanist for our project. I have a project with a couple of tasks through phabricator. As soon as I create a revision through `arc diff` for feature branch (`A`), I want to start in a different feature branch (`B`) before the revision is closed. How can I call arcanist so that a new diff and revision is created for every single branch alone? When I switch branches and try `arc diff`, it just adds the new revision and diff to the one before.

Answer (score 2):

Are there changes from `A` and `B` depends on each other?

If No:

For example you're at `master` now and create new `A` branch with `git checkout -b A`, make your changes and that push it to review with `arc diff master`.

Now you can go back to master and create new `B` branch from it with

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b "B"
```

make changes and push it to review with `arc diff master`. You will have two reviews for `A` and `B`

If Yes: you pushed your changes for review for `A` branch. Now you can create new `B` branch from `A` with: `git checkout -b B`, make your changes and push it to review with:

```
arc diff A
```

after it you will have also two reviews for `A` and `B`

Comment: After trying this method (no, changes from `B` do not concern `A`), arcanist tries to update the revision before with the commits of feature branch `B` instead of creating a new revision only for feature branch `B`.

Comment: Same Problem here, when I have two independent branches `A` and `B`, with creating the second diff for `B` arcanist wants to update the  revision for `A`.